# C# Selenium webdriver button click

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click this button through Selenium web driver but it whatever I try, it says cannot find element.

```
<a class="button" href="#" id="enrollForm">ENROLL NOW</a>
```

I tried

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='enrollForm']")).Click();
```

Update:

This is the whole snippet. I want to click on the button "Enroll Now":

```
<div class="buttonContainerLanding"> 
    <div class="buttonDiv"> 
        <a class="button" href="#" id="enrollForm">ENROLL NOW</a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="buttonDiv"> 
        <!-- <b class="buttonTitle">Need to Activate Your Card?</b> --> 
        <a class="button" href="#" id="activate">ACTIVATE CARD</a> 
    </div> 
    <div class="buttonDiv"> 
        <!-- <b class="buttonTitle">Need to Activate Your Card?</b> --> 
        <a class="button" href="#" id="replace">REPLACE CARD</a> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Check if you anchor element is inside frame ...You will have to switch to that frame first before trying to lookup element.

Comment: I am guessing, the element is not visible during run time or the “id” value is changing with every refresh/fresh page load. As mentioned by @nish26, please check if the element is present in a frame. Try switching to a frame and then try Also, please attach HTML structure

Comment: Can you please post error stack?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **ENROLL NOW** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LinkText`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("ENROLL NOW"));
  ```
- Using `CssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.buttonContainerLanding div.buttonDiv>a.button#enrollForm"));
  ```
- Using `XPath`:

  ```
  driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='buttonContainerLanding']//div[@class='buttonDiv']/a[@id='enrollForm' and text()='ENROLL NOW']"));
  ```